# XML files not moving to META-INF folder of jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-jar-plugin

I am creating  a jar out of my codebase with selectes packages. Also i need the xml files to be moved to META-INF folder. But i dont see that happening though my jar gets created.

```
<build>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>jboss-ejb3.xml</include>
            <include>ejb-jar.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF</targetPath>
    </resource>
</resources>

 <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>com/**/server/*EJB.class</include>
                <include>com/**/common/*Remote.class</include>
            </includes>
            <!-- <archive> -->
                <!-- <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor> -->
            <!-- </archive> -->
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

When i use Maven-resource-plugin i could see the **META-INF** folder generated in target folder. But not seeing the same inside **jar**.

Comment: Why not just place them in `src/main/resources/META-INF`? Then they will be automatically added., no need to add the resources plugin.

Comment: i tried that as well. That perfectly works fine when i create a jar without using any file filters (<include>). But when i filter certain packages, then META-INF does not gets moved to jar.

Comment: When you filter with include you must add everything you want to include, including `META-INF`... If something doesn't match the include filter it will be excluded. But why do you need an include filter in the first place? Shouldn't everything simply be part of the jar?

Comment: Have tried that too. But same outcome. i used as below.
<includes>
      <include>src/main/resources/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml</include>
      <include>src/main/resources/META-INF/jboss-ejb3.xml</include>
      <include>com/**/server/*EJB.class</include>
      <include>com/**/common/*Remote.class</include>
     </includes>

Comment: You should have `META-INF/**` NOT `src/main/resources/META-INF` and then it should be included. But again why do you need an include filter in the first place. It filters the `target` directory NOT the sources.

Comment: oh Yes!! got it. its working now. Thanks to you.
I am currently migrating a legacy project from ANT based build to Maven. Here from a single codebase they are creating multiple jars. Like a, b, c classes to one jar, x, y, z classes into another and so on. Hence using the filters.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using `<include>META-INF/**</include>` as suggested by user **M.Deinum**